# How to use OpenCV to find the contours of a line in an image and mark the starting point of the line?

Tags: opencv

[image]

On the left is the original image, and on the right is the result.I want to detect the hair in the image and mark the endpoints of each hair.But the actual running result of the program is not what I wanted.
Here is my code and running results.

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("images/3.png", cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
t, th = cv2.threshold(image, 75, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
k1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))
x0 = cv2.erode(th, k1, iterations=2)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(x0, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for i in range(len(contours)):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])

    M = cv2.moments(contours[i])
    cx = int(M['m10'] / M['m00'])
    cy = int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])

    cv2.drawContours(image, contours, i, (0,255,0），1, 8）
    cv2.drawMarker(image, (cx, cy),(0,0,255），1,4,1）

cv2.imshow("src", image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I have tried using the FLD algorithm, but it cannot determine the endpoint of a line segment

Comment: You are going to have another problem... your lines have 2 ends each.

Comment: Only detect lines within the image area

Comment: Maybe try `rotatedRect()` and look for where your objects touch the short edge.